# Java and Google Spreadsheets API Authorization with OAuth 2.0

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I want to read Google Spreadsheets using Java, and the recommended way to do this is using the [Google Spreadsheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/).

The problem begins when you want to make procedures secure, so they encourage you to use OAuth 2.0. In the [official page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#authorizing_requests) they show how to do this using only .NET and say that "*the Java client library doesn't currently support OAuth 2.0*", and they give alternatives like using `OAuth 1.0` or `Client Login` using directly *email* and *password*.

Is this for sure?, isn't there a way to do OAuth 2.0 Authentication through Java, maybe not using directly the Java client library, but through requests with specific parameters.

Please I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: for anyone interested on this, there is a tutorial on this link: http://soatutorials.blogspot.com/2013/08/google-spreadsheet-api-connecting-with.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Data Java Client Library now supports OAuth 2.0:

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/detail?r=505

Unfortunately, there are no complete samples in the library showing how to use it. I'd recommend checking these two links to put together the information to make it work:

- https://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/wiki/OAuth2
- https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2

Answer (score 12):

I also found it quite silly that the [developer docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#authorizing_requests_with_oauth_20) provided Java examples for everything except OAuth2.  Here's some sample code that I used to get it working.  For completeness it includes the [retrieving spreadsheets example](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#retrieving_a_list_of_spreadsheets) in the later section.  Note also that you have to add the required scopes to the Java DrEdit example as shown below.

```
public class GSpreadsheets {

    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "YOUR_SECRET_ID";
    private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        if (CLIENT_ID.equals("YOUR_CLIENT_ID") || CLIENT_SECRET.equals("YOUR_SECRET_ID")) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "TODO: Get client ID and SECRET from https://cloud.google.com/console");
        }

            // get credentials similar to Java DrEdit example
            // https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/java
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                httpTransport, jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET,
                Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE, 
                              "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", 
                              "https://docs.google.com/feeds"))
                .setAccessType("online")
                .setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();

        String url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).build();
        System.out.println("Please open the following URL in your "
                + "browser then type the authorization code:");
        System.out.println("  " + url);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String code = br.readLine();

        GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setFromTokenResponse(response);

            // create the service and pass it the credentials you created earlier
        SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("MyAppNameHere");
        service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);

        // Define the URL to request.  This should never change.
        URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(
            "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");

        // Make a request to the API and get all spreadsheets.
        SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
        List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

        // Iterate through all of the spreadsheets returned
        for (SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet : spreadsheets) {
          // Print the title of this spreadsheet to the screen
          System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Edit]

### Java OAuth2 code

Blog post on [google-spreadsheet-api] and OAuth2, with code
http://soatutorials.blogspot.co.at/2013/08/google-spreadsheet-api-connecting-with.html

*Related question:* [OAuth2 authorization from Java/Scala using google gdata client API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27572617/oauth2-authorization-from-java-scala-using-google-gdata-client-api)

[end edit]

I used: Google drive **DrEdit** tutorial, full example shows how to use OAuth 2.0 with Drive. The code works with google spreadsheets GData style API. (note: does not include refresh token, but the refresh token works as you would expect, so not hard too add.) -

Extra Note: A better documented API is Google-Apps-Script.