# using the google sheets api

Tags: android, google-api, google-sheets-api

I want to be able to edit a google spreadsheet from a Android app.

I read that I need to do the OAuth 2.0 and only after that I can access the API.

in the Authorizing with Google for REST APIs in the android werbsite, it says:

```
Note: An OAuth 2.0 token using GoogleAuthUtil is required only for certain types of Google APIs that
 you need to access over HTTP. If you're instead using the Google Play services library to access 
Google APIs such as Google+ or Play Games, you don't need an OAuth 2.0 token and you can instead
access these services using the GoogleApiClient. For more information, read Accessing Google Play
Services APIs.
```

My question is:
**What should I use for the Sheets API?**

the Google Play services library and GoogleApiClient?

or the  GoogleAuthUtil and the example on the page?

**Its really not clear to me what is the correct way to do the OAuth 2.0 for the sheets API.**

thnaks!

Comment: I think you're looking for [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#authorizing_requests).

Comment: thanks for your answer! I saw this document but the OAuth 2.0 part, for some reason, in only available in .NET , I am writing a Android app and I could not find any good example of the OAuth 2.0 in android (for the sheets API)

Comment: From what I have understood you need to use Google Play Services & GoogleApiClient and not GoogleAuthToken. GoogleAuthToken will only provide you a token. In your case, you also need to specify Google APIs you would use along with Google Drive's scope (since you would want user to create a worksheet as well). GoogleApiClient.Builder can help you with that. Providing an [example](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/02/new-client-api-model-in-google-play.html) for the same.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I will look at it. just want to add that I don't want to create a spreadsheet, just add lines and write text to an existing spreadsheet. so, do I still need the Drive api? or just the sheets api? thanks again!

Comment: I don't think Drive's API should be needed for just manipulating the cells. But its my speculation.

Comment: @VarunSingh is right. You don't need drive API to update a spreadsheet, but you do need it to create a new spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

### OAuth2 and Google-spreadsheet-API

These are independent -- You get the OAuth2 access & re-fresh tokens and then use the access token with the google-spreadsheet-api.

### Understanding OAuth Tokens

For a basic understanding of the tokens see this blog and the references to "Google OAuth2.0 Playground."
http://masashi-k.blogspot.jp/2013/06/sending-mail-with-gmail-using-xoauth2.html

### OAuth2 & Java

I have not tried this, but looks like the best tutorial I have seen. 
http://soatutorials.blogspot.co.at/2013/08/google-spreadsheet-api-connecting-with.html
From: [OAuth2 authorization from Java/Scala using google gdata client API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27572617/oauth2-authorization-from-java-scala-using-google-gdata-client-api)

OR the google DrEdit tutorial includes OAuth2

Comment: first, thanks for your answer. I will try it , but from what I see in the code, there is a clientSecret and a clientID, and in my google console for the Android Application I only have a client ID.

Comment: See edit - I added a link to a "google OAuth Playground" blog.

Comment: The example in the link in for a Web Application. I have a android application (installed application), and when you choose installed application - google provides only client Id (don't have client secret).. so I am not sure how to use the code or the google OAuth Playground