# Logging Temp and Humidity Data with Google Docs

Tags: google-sheets-api, raspberry-pi2

I am working on a science project, and need to record temperature and humidity on Google Spreadsheets. I am using the DHT11 sensor with a Raspberry Pi. I know my sensor works (I have gotten data from it to print in the terminal), but cannot get it to automatically record it to a spreadsheet.

I have followed all the instructions here (https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/dht-humidity-sensing-on-raspberry-pi-with-gdocs-logging.pdf)
and here (http://gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2.html#), but I get an error message each time, specifically

"Unable to login and get spreadsheet. Check OAuth credentials, spreadsheet name, and make sure the spreadsheet is shared to the client_email address in the OAuth .json file!
Google sheet login failed with error: '(email address it gave me)'"

I also receive an email in my main email saying that the domain name is not found for the email address I tried to send the Google Spreadsheet to.

I am at a total loss with all of this. I don't understand CS much at all, but am ready to learn!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you create a service account in Google credentials?

Comment: OAuth issue & Spreadsheet API: There is a good blog post http://soatutorials.blogspot.co.at/2013/08/google-spreadsheet-api-connecting-with.html Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938514/java-and-google-spreadsheets-api-authorization-with-oauth-2-0/16007453?s=1|0.4450#16007453  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857866/using-the-google-sheets-api/27882556?s=2|0.1861#27882556

Comment: Yes, I created a service account, dowloaded the .json file, took the information from there and put it into the code where it was needed. I double-checked that it was in the right place several times and I made several service accounts and used the information from each, just to be sure. I also made sure the .json file was in the correct place on the hard-drive.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at those links.