# Maven dependency for Google Spreadsheet

Tags: java, maven, google-sheets-api

Added the following dependency in `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-data-spreadsheet-v3</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.10-alpha</version>
</dependency>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. It doesn't contain any of the required classes. For example, `SpreadsheetService`, `SpreadsheetFeed`, `SpreadsheetEntry`etc.

Is there any other maven repository for Google Spreadsheet?

Also, in [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/setup) documentation, they haven't mentioned any maven repository. So, do I have to manually download the required JARs and add them to my project?

Comment: According to [MVN Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api.client/google-api-data-spreadsheet-v3/1.0.10-alpha) this artifact exists in the Maven Central Repository. I am able to depend on it. Your problem description "it doesn't seem to work" is not enough to let us help you.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose It doesn't contain any of the required classes. For example, `SpreadsheetService`, `SpreadsheetFeed`, `SpreadsheetEntry`etc. Can't get any imports for them.

Comment: You are right. This artifact does not contain anything. The main question is: Why did you add the dependency to it?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I didn't know prior to adding it and then I wasn't able to find any alternative in maven.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose No issues. Found the repository. Adding as answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some searching and experimentation, I finally found the dependency which contains the required classes to work with Google Spreadsheets. Here it is -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.47.1</version>
</dependency>
```

To test this, I used the code given [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/worksheets#retrieve_a_list_of_spreadsheets).

As far as getting authorization is concerned, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21124247/6042824) answer.

Comment: Well ... this is not a _repository_, it is a simple _dependency_ on an artifact.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose my bad.